# Leave out parentheses in method call

Tags: scala

I am writing a DSL in Scala where I'd like to achieve a chain of method calls as follows:

```
def x(i:Int) = i
x 1 equals 1 //doesn't compile
```

I am not sure why the compiler is happy if I leave out the second parentheses but not the first one:

```
x(1) equals 1 //works fine
```

Is there a way to achieve the first version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke methods without parenthesis, but not functions.

So the following works:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   def x(i:Int) = i
     | }
defined object Foo

scala> Foo x 1
res9: Int = 1

scala> Foo x 1 equals 1
res10: Boolean = true
```